# Variable no se guarda en Ionic 3

Tags: angularjs, ionic, typescript, ionic3

Cuando quiero guardar un dato en un variable, ésta se guarda y lo muestra en consola, pero si quiero usarla en otro lado, me dice que esta `undefined` y no se que hacer.

Aquí un fragmento de ese código:

```
public valoractual:number;
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker,i) {
            return function() {
              this.valoractual=i;
              console.log(this.valoractual);//me la imprime aqui pero ni puedo usarla afuera
              infowindow.setContent(locationtemp[i]);
              infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
            }
          })(marker,i));
```

Esto solo me pasa cuando trato de hacerlo dentro de un marcador y no se como arreglarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es ambigua y le faltan detalles, diría que el problema es que metes una función anónima adentro de otra y no regresas el resultado al contexto correspondiente, intenta de esta forma.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (marker, i) => {
  this.valoractual = i;
  console.log(this.valoractual);
  infowindow.setContent(locationtemp[i]);
  infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
});
```